# How do I create a code segment for a pipeline to return duplicate Strings in Java 8

Tags: java

I'm creating a pipeline in Java 8 that is able to take a list of students and the name of their clubs that they joined. I want to generate a list of students that joined multiple clubs, so basically I need to return the duplicate names of students that joined 2 or more clubs.

This is my data.txt file where the pipeline is getting the required data.

```
ARTS:Joey Solydan:Economics
MUSIC:Joey Solydan:Economics 
ARTS:Haley Wolloims:WomenStudies
SPORTS:Godfriey Lemonsquesser:Cookery 
LITERATURECLUB:Say Moniki:Archeology 
FILM:Milles Spielberg:Masscom
ARTS:Milles Spielberg:Masscom
```

Basically, I need the code to return the names of Joey Solydan and Milles Spielberg because they are in 2 clubs unlike the other names.

So the next step is to create a method to look for Joey and Milles using Java 8 lambda and I started off the method as such:

```
public static void displayDuplicateNames(ArrayList<Member> member) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Set<Member>>> allMembers = new TreeMap<>();


    //For loop to initialize the Map
    for (Member members : member) {
        String club = members.getClub();
        String name = members.getName();
        Map<String, Set<Member>> clubList = allMembers.computeIfAbsent(org, k -> new TreeMap<>());
        Set<Member> nameList = clubList.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new TreeSet<>());
        nameList.add(members);
    }
```

next is to create the pipeline and it follows just after the for loop:

```
 allMembers
            .forEach(
                    (club, clubList) -> {
                        System.out.printf("\n*** Club %s:", club);
                        clubList
                                .forEach(
                                        (name, nameList) ->{
                                            System.out.printf("\n** Member's Name with Multiple Clubs:  %s\n", name);     
                                            // I got stumped on what to do next   
                                        }
                                );
                    });
```

I want an expected output of something like:

```
*** Club Arts: 
    ** Member's Name with Multiple Clubs:  Joey Solydan
    ** Member's Name with Multiple Clubs:  Milles Spielberg

*** Club Music:
    ** Member's Name with Multiple Clubs:  Joey Solydan

*** Club Film:
    ** Member's Name with Multiple Clubs:  Milles Spielberg
```

UPDATE:

I've followed the code segment from WJS and the current code looks like this:

```
public static List<String> displayDuplicateNames(ArrayList<Member> member) {
    Map<String, Integer> dups = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Set<Member>>> allMembers = new TreeMap<>();

    for (Member members : member) {
        String org = members.getOrg();
        String name = members.getName();
        Map<String, Set<Member>> orgList = allMembers.computeIfAbsent(org, k -> new TreeMap<>());
        Set<Member> nameList = orgList.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new TreeSet<>());
        nameList.add(members);
    }

    allMembers
            .forEach(
                    (org, orgList) -> {
                        System.out.printf("\n*** Organization %s: ", org);
                        orgList
                                .forEach(
                                        (name, nameList) ->{
                                            System.out.printf("\n** Member's Name with Multiple Organizations:  %s\n", name);
                                            if (dups.containsKey(name)) {
                                                dups.put(name, dups.get(name) + 1);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                dups.put(name, 1);
                                            }

                                        }

                                );
                    });
    return dups.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1).map(
            Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My method for reading the data from the file has been updated as well:

```
    public static List<Member> readDataFromFile(String filename)
{
    String line = "";
    ArrayList<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split("[:]");
            String club = parts[1];
            String name = parts[2];
            String course = parts[0];
            memberList.add(new Member(club,name,course));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR, FILE NOT FOUND.");
    }
    return memberList;
}
```

The current output is now:

[image]

It shows the members of each club but now I need to just show each club with a member that is joined with another club other than theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility.

Put this at the top of the dups method.

```java
            Map<String, Integer> dups = new HashMap<>();
```

Add the following code at your comment

```java
            if (dups.containsKey(name)) {
               dups.put(name, dups.get(name) + 1);
            }
            else {
               dups.put(name, 1);
            }
```

and return this at the end of the method.

```java
           return dups.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1).map(
               Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Finally, make certain your displayDups method returns a `List<String>`

Here is your modified method.

```java
 public static List<String> displayDuplicateNames(List<Member> members) {
      Map<String, Map<String, Set<Member>>> allMembers = new TreeMap<>();
      Map<String, Integer> dups = new HashMap<>();
      // For loop to initialize the Map
      for (Member member : members) {
         String club = member.getClub();
         String name = member.getName();
         Map<String, Set<Member>> clubList =
               allMembers.computeIfAbsent(club, k -> new TreeMap<>());
         Set<Member> nameList =
               clubList.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new TreeSet<>());
         nameList.add(member);
      }
      allMembers.forEach((club, clubList) ->
      {
         System.out.printf("%n*** Club %s:%n", club);
         clubList.forEach((name, nameList) ->
         {
            System.out.printf("   ** Member's Name with Multiple Clubs:  
            %s%n",
                  name);
            if (dups.containsKey(name)) {
               dups.put(name, dups.get(name) + 1);
            }
            else {
               dups.put(name, 1);
            }
         });
      });

      return dups.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1).map(
            Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
}
```

It returns

`dups = [Joey Solydan, Milles Spielberg]`

Note that I had to make my own Member class since it was not included in your question.  So I added getters to retrieve the values.

Comment: Where did the  variable Entry come from?

Comment: It's the interface name defined in the Map interface.  So it can be used as a method reference to access the key or value (in this case the key).

Comment: Note that `Entry` can also be referenced as `Map.Entry` if it doesn't resolve properly depending on your imports.

Comment: for some reason it's returning the wrong values, instead of the expected value it returns something like: 
   


      *** Organization Archeology: 
      ** Member's Name with Multiple 
      Organizations:  LITERATURECLUB

Comment: Not certain what the problem is. I will post my version of your duplicates code.

Comment: I have used your updated method but it still returns all members of each club for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind processing you input twice you could first count how often your students enrolled. Assuming you have all your students in the list memberList:

```java
Map<string, Long> counted = memberList.stream()
            .map(member -> member.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Now counted contains all names once with a count of how often they came up.

Next you could take your memberList and do

```java
stream().filter(member -> counted[member.name] > 1)
```

That (after collecting yada yada) should result in a list which only contains Members enrolled in more than one club.

Hope the syntax is correct. Didn't code Java for a while now :-)

Comment: Within the Map itself why is there a Long variable?

Comment: For the counter.